# Problem/bug with Promise.race() on serverless(loading cache from previous calls)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, async-await, serverless-framework

The application is running in NodeJs and we are using Promise.race() to timeout the main promise, as show in the code (here the “mainPromise” is a generic promise for testing).

```js
const promiseTimeout = new Promise((resolve, _) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise Timeout');
  }, 20000);
});

const mainPromise = new Promise((resolve, _) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Main promise finished');
  }, 21000);
});

export const triggerVerifySls = async (event: any, context: any) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  const triggerStatus = await Promise.race([mainPromise, promiseTimeout]);

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(triggerStatus),
  };

  return response;
};
```

When we deploy and call the function it works the first time, but in other calls, the Promise.race return the response of the first promise in the array.

**Output with Promise.race([mainPromise, promiseTimeout])**

```
$ Serverless reponse: promise Timeout
$ Serverless reponse: Main promise finished
$ Serverless reponse: Main promise finished
$ Serverless reponse: Main promise finished
```

Output with Promise.race([promiseTimeout, mainPromise])

```
$ Serverless reponse: promise Timeout
$ Serverless reponse: promise Timeout
$ Serverless reponse: promise Timeout
$ Serverless reponse: promise Timeout
```

It seems the function has the response cached, because it didn’t wait 20 seconds after the first call:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpTZj.png)

- Does the function cache the response?
- Does the function support Promise.race?

**SERVERLESS.YML**

```yaml
frameworkVersion: '2'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  memorySize: 2052
  timeout: 30
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  triggerVerifySls:
    handler: src/serverless/triggerVerifySls.triggerVerifySls
    events:
      - http:
          path: triggerVerifySls
          method: post
```

Comment: Once a promise resolves, a cached value will be returned for all upcoming calls since promises live outside of the handler function.

Comment: You can check that simply by moving promises inside the function so every time the function gets called a new instance of Promise is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah like the comments say, make your fake promise's functions instead of const promises:

```
const promiseTimeout = () => new Promise((resolve, _) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('promise Timeout');
  }, 20000);
});

const mainPromise = () => new Promise((resolve, _) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve('Main promise finished');
  }, 21000);
});
```

Then call it like so:

```
const triggerStatus = await Promise.race([mainPromise(), promiseTimeout()]);
...
```